# How to compile and link python3 wrapper functions using gcc

Tags: python, c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile some C wrapper functions to Python 3.4 using gcc and makefile, but I am having no success in finding the correct compile and link flags. I am using Ubuntu 14

Right now this is what I was trying in the makefile:

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -std=c99 `pkg-config --cflags python3` 
LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs python3` 

final: functions.o wrapper.o
$(CC) -o functions.o $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

functions.o: functions.c functions.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c functions.c

wrapper.o: wrapper.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g -c wrapper.c
```

Using this get me this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.4m.a(dynload_shlib.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Also, I have little experience in makefiles, so I don't if I have done something wrong along the way

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes, got the same error

Comment: Building against the static library will not make you happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably find a good tutorial on Makefiles, but this one should get you started:

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -std=c99 `pkg-config --cflags python-3.4`
CFLAGS  += -fPIC
LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs python-3.4`

all: myfunctions.so

myfunctions.so: wrapper.o functions.o
    $(CC) -shared $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

If you are creating C wrappers for Python you need to create a shared object. To do that at a minimum you have to use `-fPIC` when compiling and use `-shared` when linking. The sample Makefile above uses the built in rules to compile `.c` files into `.o` files. The shared object in this example will be created as `myfunctions.so`, but you can change `myfunctions.so:` to whatever you'd prefer to call it. This Makefile can be called with `make all` to generate the shared object.